# Alignment Problem

Tags: theme-development, themes, child-theme, theme-customizer, theme-options

I have an alignment problem with datetime of the comment "not post". The main problem is that I'm on RTL mode and the theme doesn't fully support such environment. So basically, the datetime of the comment inside the post page is placed on the user's avatar. I couldn't find that specific datetime. I searched everywhere. Can anyone please help me to fix this? [My site](https://www.badee.net/linux) Please see the screenshots. The theme I'm using is called Steed and I can't find a fix for that problem.

[image: This is how it should look like.]

[image: This is what I got.]

Thank you,
Badee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The avatar image is overlapped because of the negative margins in this CSS:

```
.comment-author.vcard img { margin-bottom: -18px; }
div.comment-metadata { margin: -5px 0 0 8.3%; }
```